# Python locally created package not being found

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, environment-variables

I have a small team of people working on a small new Python project.
I created a small package called Environment.

This has two files:
Setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='Environment', version='1.0', packages=find_packages())
```

root.py

```
ROOT_DIR = "STATIC_VALUE_15"
```

When I use `pip install -e .` and then run the project within the anaconda enviroment I use for this project, I can run files that use this Environment package. However when other people use the same branch and do the same steps, they get the error:

`Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError`

They are also using their conda environment and running the project the same way in vsc.
When anyone uses pip list, for this package our paths are all correct.

Are there any suggestions for things that I could try and test to get it to work on their system, or why it works on mine and not theirs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Setup.py` is deprecated, use `pyproject.toml` instead.

```py
[build-system]
requires = ["hatchling"]
build-backend = "hatchling.build"

[project]
name = "environment"
version = "1.0.0"
```

You also need to follow this file hierarchy:

```
package_project/
└── src/
    └── environment/
        ├── __init__.py
        └── root.py
```

You may read [Packaging Python Projects](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/). There is plenty of room to make mistake, I struggled a lot in the past because I forgot a file, or didn't follow the file hierarchy, and if the build fail, sometime you can still run or import the code because of your python environment.

If you want to test if it works for someone else without having someone else, you can `build` the package and install it in an other environment where the sources are not easily accessible for python, using the `.whl`.